# Function pointer and struct self inclusion

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, declaration, typedef

I need the following construct:

```
// Header file

typedef fc_t (*comdevCbackIsReady_t)(const comdev_t* const module);

typedef struct
{
    comdevCbackIsReady_t    cbIsReady;  

} comdev_t;
```

This wont compile, because the `comdevCbackIsReady_t` function pointer type does not know the `comdev_t` struct type. If I exchange these 2 places, then the struct wont know the func pointer type. My current way around this is declaring the `comdevCbackIsReady_t` input parameter as `void*` instead. This is not very clean. Is there a way to somehow "forward declare" one of these?

EDIT this wont compile:

```
// Header file

struct comdev_t;

typedef fc_t (*comdevCbackIsReady_t)(const comdev_t* const module);

typedef struct
{
    comdevCbackIsReady_t    cbIsReady;  

} comdev_t;
```

The `comdev_t` is still an unknown type for the `comdevCbackIsReady_t`.

Comment: You can't compile header files.

Comment: you need to look at the answer below to get the correct syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this typedef declaration of a function pointer

```
typedef fc_t (*comdevCbackIsReady_t)(const comdev_t* const module);
```

the used name `comdev_t` is not declared yet. So the compiler issues an error.

You could just introduce the tag name in the structure declaration like

```
struct comdev_t;

typedef fc_t (*comdevCbackIsReady_t)(const struct comdev_t* const module);

typedef struct comdev_t
{
    comdevCbackIsReady_t    cbIsReady;  

} comdev_t;
```

Or

```
typedef struct comdev_t comdev_t;

typedef fc_t (*comdevCbackIsReady_t)(const comdev_t* const module);

struct comdev_t
{
    comdevCbackIsReady_t    cbIsReady;  

};
```

Comment: Neither will work, either if initially compiles. As soon as any function is to be created to be passed as the created function pointer, it wont recognize the type.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło The code I showed will work. If you have some other problems with a code that you did not show you should show it. Of course the structure declaration must be known in the translation unit where the functions are defined,

Comment: That is probably the problem. I would like to include that header and declare an actual function elsewhere- that's a different translation unit.

Comment: All and all, I think using a `void*` ptr is still the least hacky/ ugly solution, but thanks...